# Nesting Suave WebPart

Tags: rest, f#, suave

I've been playing around Suave for the very first time and clearly there's something I don't understand. 
What I'm trying to achieve is to implement a simple Rest API:

- user can get information about financial instruments
- moreover, every instrument has a list of prices

For now for simplicity I focus on GET methods only.

My ***very*** basic piece of code is here:

```
[<AutoOpen>]
module RestFul =    

    let JSON v =     
        let jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
        jsonSerializerSettings.ContractResolver <- new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()

        JsonConvert.SerializeObject(v, jsonSerializerSettings)
        |> OK 
        >=> Writers.setMimeType "application/json; charset=utf-8"

    let fromJson<'a> json =
        JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, typeof<'a>) :?> 'a    

    let getResourceFromReq<'a> (req : HttpRequest) = 
        let getString rawForm = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(rawForm)
        req.rawForm |> getString |> fromJson<'a>

    type RestResource<'a> = {
        GetById : int -> 'a option
        GetPricesById : int -> 'a option
    }

    let rest resource =

        let handleResource requestError = function
            | Some r -> r |> JSON
            | _ -> requestError

        let getResourceById = 
            resource.GetById >> handleResource (NOT_FOUND "Resource not found")

        let getPricesById = 
            resource.GetPricesById >> handleResource (NOT_FOUND "Resource not found")

        choose [
            GET >=> pathScan "/instrument/%d" getResourceById
            GET >=> pathScan "/instrument/%d/prices" getPricesById
        ]


module Main =
    [<EntryPoint>]
    let main argv = 

        let webPart = rest {
                GetById = fun i -> Some i // placeholder
                GetPricesById = fun i -> Some i // placeholder, it'll be a list eventually
            }

        startWebServer defaultConfig webPart
        0
```

When I define the WebPart in this way:

```
choose [
    GET >=> pathScan "/instrument/%d" getResourceById // Returns the instrument static data
    GET >=> pathScan "/instrument/%d/prices" getPricesById // Returns price list for the instrument
]
```

Then everything works fine. I'm wondering if there's a way to nest the webparts, e.g. like this:

```
// My idea about the code - doesn't compile
choose [
    pathScan "/instrument/%d" getResourceById >=> choose [
        GET // Returns the instrument static data
        GET >=> path "/prices" >=> (somehow refer to the previous id and get prices)  // Returns price list for the instrument
    ]
]
```

Also - as I'm learning about the RestAPIs there might be a gap in my reasoning. I think that nesting prices endpoint in that way makes it simply clear that prices are considered a property of an instrument (feel free to correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: This is not how it works. You have to let go of the concept of "current request". There is no such thing in Suave. It's all function composition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right, so accessing a previous request is kind of anti suave ;) we want things to be able to happen independently regardless of what just happened. So perhaps a better way of thinking solving this would be simply appending prices to the end of the path?

```
choose [
    GET >=> pathScan "/instrument/%d" getResourceById 
    GET >=> pathScan "/instrument/%d/prices" getPricesById
]
```

Comment: So exactly as in my current solution, right (i.e. the one that I posted and which works) ?
Also - thanks for the explanation of what is considered "anti-suave". That's something I wanted to hear.

Comment: I don't think he is trying to access a *previous request*. More like a previous part of the nested `pathScan` chain. Which is a feature request that has come up more than once (people asking for some sort of `subPath` combinator), though right now I can't find where those other feature requests were submitted. If I find them, I'll link them. But right now, Suave doesn't offer that feature.